# how to calculate mortgage in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I have formula for finding monthly payment with four fields

1. Loan Amount
2. Interest Rate
3. Terms of loan
4. Monthly Payment

`Formula: Monthly Payment =Loan amount * ((1 + Interest rate per annum/100) ^ Term of loan) / Term of loan / 12`

Now I want to find

1. Loan Amount
2. Interest Rate
3. Terms of loan

if any of three fields are populated.

I have also formula for calculating loan amount based on interest rate, terms of loan and monthly payment.

```
Formula: Loan amount = Monthly Payment/ ((1 + Interest rate per annum/100) ^ Term of loan) * Term of loan * 12
```

But it does not calculating perfect figure.

Any one can give me these three formulas for calculating loan amount/interest rate/terms of loan (java script will be more appreciated)

Comment: But where's the JavaScript code with that formula? What's not working?

Comment: You already have the formula. Converting it to code is not going to be difficult, is there a more specific problem you needed addressed?

Comment: I want to find any of field based on three fields populated from four fields. So I want four formulas. 1) For monthly payment which I have and it is working 2) For Loan amount formula 3) For Interest rate formula and 4) For terms of loan

Answer (score 19):

Here is mine,

the formula :

```
M = P [ i(1 + i)^n ] / [ (1 + i)^n – 1]
```

<sup>[nerdWallet](http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/finance/mortgage/faq/calculate-monthly-mortgage-payment/)</sup>

Hope this helps in someway

```js
var M; //monthly mortgage payment
var P = 400000; //principle / initial amount borrowed
var I = 3.5 / 100 / 12; //monthly interest rate
var N = 30 * 12; //number of payments months

//monthly mortgage payment
M = monthlyPayment(P, N, I);

console.log(M);

function monthlyPayment(p, n, i) {
  return p * i * (Math.pow(1 + i, n)) / (Math.pow(1 + i, n) - 1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the interest is 0. I know that it's a rare case scenario but a perfect function should cover it

Comment: This doesn't match what I see here: http://www.calculator.net/payment-calculator.html?ctype=fixterm&cloanamount=1000&cloanterm=2&cmonthlypay=1000&cinterestrate=60&printit=0&x=99&y=11

Answer (score 1):

```
var deno = (100 + Interest_rate_per_annum)/100;
var pdeno = Math.pow(deno, Term_of_Loan);
var loan_amount = (Monthly_payment * Term_of_Loan * 12) / pdeno;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact same answer as @shay gave but with the variable names spelled out to make it easier for me to understand:

```
// totalPayments should be the total number of payments expected to be made for the life of the loan: years * 12
// interestRate: eg. 6.2% should be passed as 0.062
function getMortgagePayment(startingLoanAmount, totalPayments, interestRate)
{
    let interestRatePerMonth = interestRate / 12;
    return startingLoanAmount * interestRatePerMonth * (Math.pow(1 + interestRatePerMonth, totalPayments)) / (Math.pow(1 + interestRatePerMonth, totalPayments) - 1);
}
```