# How would I write this formula in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a project I am working on and it needs to calculate mortgage calculations but I'm having trouble putting the formula into javascript.

the formula is:

M = P I(1 + I)^n /(1 + I )^n - 1

Any help is appreciated, thanks

P = loan princible

I = interest

N = Term

Comment: What have you researched and tried?  Which parts can you do yourself and which parts did you have questions about? Hint, see [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

Comment: Being more specific let's us help you easier. What is `P`? A number I assume?

Comment: I have all my variables but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the math with javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safe evaluation of arithmetic expressions in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066824/safe-evaluation-of-arithmetic-expressions-in-javascript)

Comment: PI is Pi, p*i im confused

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101442/how-to-calculate-mortgage-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into a sequence of steps.

- Multiplication is as straightforward as it gets: `I*(1+I)`
- Division is the same: `I/(1+I)`
- To the power of `n` is denoted by: `Math.pow(3, 5); //3 to the power of 5`

`Math.pow()` might be the only thing you didn't know yet.

---

Unrelated but useful,

Wrap your formula into a function and you have a mortgage-calculation function

`calculateMortgage(p,i,n) {
 result = //translate the formula in the way I indicated above
 return result;
}`

and call it like so:

`var mortgage = calculateMortgage(300,3,2); // 'mortgage' variable will now hold the mortgage for L=300, I=3, N=2`

Also, the formula you posted really doesn't make any sense - why is there a blank between `P` & `I` at the very beginning? Something's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `Math.pow(p*i*(1+i),n)/Math.pow(1+i,n-1)`

Math.pow(a,2) is same as a^2

if P is not supposed to be with numerator then
this

`p * (Math.pow(i*(1+i),n)/Math.pow(1+i,n-1))`

or

`p * (Math.pow((i+i*i),n)/Math.pow(1+i,n-1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
var M;
var P;
var I;

M = P*(Math.pow(I*(1+I),n)) / (Math.pow((1+I),n)-1);
```

Does this look right to you? I got the correctly styled formula from [here.](http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/finance/mortgage/faq/calculate-monthly-mortgage-payment/)

Like what Nicholas above said, you can use functions to make it all the more easier.

```
var M;
function calculateMortgage(P, I, N){
    M = P*(Math.pow(I*(1+I),n)) / (Math.pow((1+I),n)-1);
    alert("Your mortgage is" + M);
}
```

And just call `calculateMortgage(100, 100, 100);` with your values for it to automatically give the answer to you.

---